# POST a query to Splunk REST API /search/jobs/ endpoint in Golang

Tags: rest, go, splunk

I would like to send a search/query to Splunk REST API, and return a search id to later consume the results.

I can achieve the desired behavior with the below `curl`:

```
#!/bin/bash

user='my_user'
pass='my_pass'

search='search index=short sourcetype=src | head 5'

curl -u $user:$pass -k https://111.22.33.44:8089/services/search/jobs -d search="$search"
```

which returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
  <sid>234523452435.6556_234234-3J3J-34J4-2345-123456678E3</sid>
</response>
```

Here are the relevant Go snippets in which I am trying to achieve the same:

Main:

```
  //main.go
    sid, err := conn.Query()
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("err creating search: %s", err)
    } else {
            fmt.Println("sid:", sid)
    }
```

Query:

```
    // query.go
    func (conn SplunkConnection) Query() (string, error) {
            data := make(url.Values)
            data.Add("output_mode", "json")
            data.Add("search%20index%3Dshort%20sourcetype%3Dsrc%20%7C%20head%205", "search")
            data.Add("-60m%40m", "earliest")
            data.Add("-10m%40m", "latest")

        // try httpGet() here
        sid, err := conn.httpPost(fmt.Sprintf("%s/services/search/jobs", conn.BaseURL), &data)
        if err != nil {
                return "", err
        }

        return string(sid), err
}
```

Helper:

```
// http.go
func (conn SplunkConnection) httpPost(url string, data *url.Values) (string, error) {
        return conn.httpCall(url, "POST", data)
}
```

What I expect is a response containing just a JSON blob with my SID. Instead, it returns a huge JSON, which appears to be contain all current jobs at the `/services/search/jobs` endpoint.

How can I adjust my code to return just the SID? (I intend to poll it for completion and retrieve the results later, but don't need help with this...yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have reversed your postdata parameters.

```
            data.Add("search%20index%3Dshort%20sourcetype%3Dsrc%20%7C%20head%205", "search")
```

This becomes `search index=short sourcetype=src | head 5` = `search`, which is the reverse of what you want.

[The key comes first, then the value](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Values.Add), but you have specified the value first, then the key.

I think this should instead be:

```
            data.Add("search", "search%20index%3Dshort%20sourcetype%3Dsrc%20%7C%20head%205")
```

I suspect the same is true of some of your other calls to `url.Values.Add()`, so you should check them all and be sure.